# Subquery Exists - Returning single column

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $6),
    EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $2 AND user_id = $6),
    EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $3 AND user_id = $6),
    EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $4 AND user_id = $6),
    EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $5 AND user_id = $6);
```

returns   5 columns   false | false | false | false | false

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgkq0.jpg

How would I make them into one column? Do I use order by?

The reason for this is because when I return the query in AWS Lamba/CloudWatch, it only gives me the first value of the row (1 false value), not all 5 values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FViI.jpg

**EDIT1:__________________________________________________________________**

I have an array of 5 values [postId1, postId2, postId3, postId4, postId5]

I want to check my table "votes" if it contains each value of the array.

That is why I am using the five "EXIST" queries above.
The query itself works perfectly in pgadmin and returns five false values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgkq0.jpg

However in AWS Cloudwatch, it only returns 1 column (1 value of false)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FViI.jpg

This is where I am unsure what the problem is. Is it because nodejs-postgres does not allow multiple SELECT statements inside a single query?

Basically this my end goal for AWS Lambda to return five "false" values.

```
"rows": [
     {
       "exists": false
     {,
     {
       "exists": false
     {,
     {
       "exists": false
     {,
     {
       "exists": false
     {,
     {
       "exists": false
     {
  ]
```

Comment: i don't know about aws lambda but i think are more easy to use case statement rather than use that exist..

Comment: What is your actual use-case? Can you describe the goal of your query in words? A data sample would help, too. We can probably come up with a better query for you, such as using an `IN` statement.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Hi, I updated the issue + the end result. Sorry for making it so confusing

Comment: @davids. But what is your _actual requirement_? Is it "tell me whether a particular user has voted for one of 5 particular IDs", or "tell me which categories a particular user has voted in", or... what?

Comment: whether the user has voted in any of the five particular ids

Answer (score 0):

you can  do this below way

```
select 
to_jsonb(array_agg(main)) as "rows"

      from (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $6) as a,
        EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $2 AND user_id = $6) as b,
        EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $3 AND user_id = $6) as c,
        EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $4 AND user_id = $6) as d,
        EXISTS (SELECT votes FROM voted WHERE id = $5 AND user_id = $6) as e) as main;
```

So it will return

```
rows
----------------------
[{"a": false, "b": false, "c": false, "d":false, "e":false}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single column you could turn the result into a JSON value, that contains key/value pairs for the ids to be tested:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(t.id::text, coalesce(t.id = v.id, false)) as result
from unnest(array[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]) as t(id)
  left join voted v on t.id = v.id and v.user_id = $6;
```

The `array[...]` contains the ID values you want to test for.

The `coalesce(t.id = v.id, false)` could also be written as `t.id is not distinct from v.id` to properly deal with missing ID values.

The result will be a JSON value that contains the ID values as keys and a true/false value if the ID was present in the table, e.g.

```
{"5": true, "8": false, "10": false, "11": false, "22": false, "42": false, "100": false}
```

If your application can handle the JSON, then this is much more flexible than your approach, because it easily scales to more values.